# When using a Repeater to create multiple GridViews, how to use an ObjectDataSource for each Gridview and add a SelectParameter to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

So, I'm trying to use a Repeater to create multiple Gridviews. (And I'm not all that well versed in ASP.NET.) But in all of the examples I've seen, within the ItemDataRowBound, individual SQL select statements are being used to provide the datasource.

I'm trying to stay within the existing framework of the application, as it has other UserControls/pages that are built to create similar-looking and functioning Gridviews.  The Gridviews are all built as a result of user text search results of the datasources. And they all use ObjectDataSources defined in their controls.    So it would be helpful if I could use ObjectDataSources instead, to source my dynamic Gridviews.

I tried creating each ObjectDataSource dynamically within the ItemDataRowBound, but when you'd click on any pagination control, pagination basically didn't happen.  And I thought about it overnight and concluded that this must be because we're creating the ObjectDataSources all over again with the postback / repeater rebinding.

So, I now have a single ObjectDataSource defined within the actual UserControl / .ascx file.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DynamicDocumentsDataSource" runat="server"
    TypeName="ConnectIT.Bll.Search" SelectMethod="GetPagedDataSet"
    EnablePaging="true" SelectCountMethod="GetRowCount"
    StartRowIndexParameterName="startRow"
    MaximumRowsParameterName="pageSize" SortParameterName="sortColumns"
    OnObjectCreated="dynamicDocuments_ObjectCreated">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="storedProc" DefaultValue="[uspGetDynamicDocuments]" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to tell the ItemDataBound method to access that control/object and add a SelectParameter to it, so that it selects slightly-different data for that Gridview.   (But something tells me that with each successive loop... as we're grabbing that same static object...I need to clear the select parameter from the previous loop iteration?? Or will it overwrite ??)

It's not inside the repeater, but I'm wondering if it needs to be?  If so, would having the same ID value for each one potentially cause problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I didn't realize that I could just reference the ObjectDataSource as it is defined in the Designer file.    I'm still in a bit of a pickle regarding getting the pagination controls to work:   The app uses a custom gridview class for every gridview.  Only I can't take a look at the class because it's a compiled .dll and who and where it came from is lost in history.   The built-in pagination controls only seem to work if the gridview is static / outside of the repeater.   I'm thinking I'll just have to ditch the custom gridview and build my own pagination controls and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would still consider dumping the SQL data source that been dumped into the aspx page. In most cases, they are can be "great" for simple things, but the instant code and WHEN the data source fires and is used? Well, we throw out those training wheels and flip to using code behind to feed the grid view.

In other words, dumping SQL data sources into that page tend over time to not only make the markup messy, but such data operations really don't belong in the page markup anyway. (Separation of UI and code logic is a good design approach).

The main issue with those SQL data sources in the markup, you have VERY little control when they are fired, and worse is trying to feed a particular parameter to the SQL data is "messy" at best, and at worst you simple can't control very well when they are used and fire.

I also dumped the use of the built in in-line editing for grid view, since there are far nicer UI choices you can make in that area also.

I am comfortable stating that instant you need code and fancy pants things (like say a repeating grid view), then that is the VERY same instant I suggest dropping the use of those SqlDatasouces.

SQL data sources are nice, since they are often wizard created. However, as a result, they are limited in use, and REALLY make a mess of the markup in the page anyway.

I mean, we can have this simple markup:

```
<h3>Enter City(s) to view</h3>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="400">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" Text="Show Hotels" CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdShow_Click" />
<br />

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <h3>Hotels for city = <%# Eval("City") %></h3>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="table table-striped"
            width="40%" >
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Note how clean the markup is.

And our code behind is thus this:

```
    protected void cmdShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable rstCities = new DataTable();
        rstCities.Columns.Add("City");
        string[] MyCities = txtCity.Text.ToString().Split(',');
        foreach (string OneCity in MyCities)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = rstCities.NewRow();
            OneRow["City"] = OneCity;
            rstCities.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = rstCities;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
            || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataRowView rowData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            GridView GV = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("GridView1");

            SqlCommand cmdSQL =
                new SqlCommand(@"SELECT FirstName, LastName, HotelName, Description
                                FROM tblHotelsC WHERE City = @City");

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rowData["City"];
            GV.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            GV.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Not a lot of code, but then again, note how easy it is to control the data source for the GV. (And more so if you build just 2-3 helper routines for this).

So, the result is now this when I type in a few cities, and display a grid view for each city showing the hotels.

[image]
So, even from a speed of development, efforts, and code written?

Not a lot of code, and the markup page is now OH so nice and clean.

You might be able to hit the Sqldatasouce with a frying pan, and "maybe" get it to trigger each time for each repeater row, and "maybe" get the correct parameter(s) to be passed.

But life is too short to "fight" the system, and the path of least resistance is the best advice I can give here.

In the above, many moons ago, I became rather tired of having to setup and type in connection strings. (To be fair, that is ONE advantage of Sqldatasources, it sets that stuff up for you).

However, I have this "helper" routine in my general code library of routines, and thus that code is this:

```
public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL, string sCon = "")
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    if (sCon == "")
        sCon = Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

So, I use above over and over all over the place in my code.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I figured out how to use a single objectdatasource that was "outside" of the repeater... and in the itemdatabound method, clear all parameters, and then re-add the stored procedure one, then add my custom parameter.   This at least works for the searches.  (Now I'm having trouble getting pagination to work.)

I wish I could simplify what I'm doing a bit, as you describe.  However, I'm stuck using the stored procedure and related code, for reasons I can't go into in one comment.

Comment: In the end, I found it a whole lot easier to remove the repeater and stick with a single ObjectDataSource and a single Gridview.   And then I went to the UserControl that was supposed to be loading this one into itself... and I rewrote things so that it dynamically loaded MULTIPLE INSTANCES of this UserControl into itself, passing each one a custom parameter that I then could apply to the ObjectDataSource as an additional SelectParameter to be used with the stored procedure.   This worked very well.

Comment: Building a user control is a way to approach this. As I stated, over time, you will still find dumping the use of "messy" and difficult SqlDataSource objects on the page still tends to produce better results. The fact that I was able with such great ease post working examples in a StackOverflow answer when no one else did? that alone speaks volumes about the ease and speed of my approach. But, to be 100% fair, adopting a user control is another path way here, and I think a great approach. However, even with a UC, I still suggest a goal to reduce use data objects in markup.